# Retrieving date range from Pandas HDF5Store

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I wish to select a date range from my HDFStore using Pandas. I noticed that my datetimes (millisecond frequency) are stored as Unix time with extra right padded zeroes i.e 1514797200002000000. I suspect my where clause is incorrect.

This is my reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path_file = "hdf5_store.h5"
data = np.random.randn(5)
cols = ["values"]
date_range = pd.date_range('20180101 09:00:00', periods=5, freq='ms')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=date_range, columns=cols)

with pd.HDFStore(path_file, mode="w", driver="H5FD_CORE") as store:
        store.append("df", df, format="table", data_columns=["date_time"], index=False)
        store.create_table_index("df", columns=["date_time"], kind="full")
        print(store["df"])

df1 = pd.read_hdf(path_file, "df", where=["date_time>1514797200002000000"])
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as a query:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(1514797200003000000)
df1 = pd.read_hdf(path_file, "df", where=["index>dt"])
```